# Doubt that / doubt if

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

I am preparing for an exam and came across this sentence in which I need to spot the error:

**One of the members (A)/ expressed doubt if (B)/ the minister was an atheist. (C) / No error (D)**

I have a grammar rule book which says that we use **doubt if / whether** in affirmative sentences and  **doubt that** in negative or interrogative. Upon googling too I came to the same conclusion but as per the solution given in the book (question bank book, it's different from a grammar rule book) it says error is in part B. I think it is No Error. What's your opinion?

Comment: "expressed doubt if" is not grammatical.

Comment: Doesn't this question fall under the church's "Don't Ask, Don't Hell" policy?

Comment: Are you sure that the book isn't talking about *doubt* as a verb?

Answer (score -1):

The sentence is ambiguous as it stands:

> One of the members expressed doubt if the minister was an atheist.

can be read as:

> One of the members expressed doubt// if the minister was an atheist.

implying the minister is variable, and so the sentence conjunction is wrong.

Instead, use:

> One of the members expressed a doubt as to whether the minister was an atheist (or not).

This makes the intended meaning clear.

Comment: ...expressed doubt about whether the minister was an atheist.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with the first answer provided. Substituting the words “as to whether” only makes it more clumsy. The “or not” is unnecessary.

The bottom line is that you can’t determine if there’s an error without knowing what the sentence is supposed to mean and the possible correction. There’s also a big difference between a sentence having an actual error and a sentence benefiting from clarification.

So when approaching this there are certain steps to take.  First, you have to determine what you think the sentence means as it is. Then you have to compare it to what it supposed to mean and finally determine any change necessary. If you can’t determine the meaning of the sentence initially, then you have to make it clearer. However, to do this, you need to know the eventual meaning.

**One of the members expressed doubt if the minister was an atheist.**

My opinion is that the meaning of the sentence is unclear. Nonetheless, I do think most people would understand that the member is unsure about the status of the minister’s beliefs. They think it possible the minister is a closeted atheist. Is the sentence worded in the clearest manner? Not at all. Is there something wrong with it? Further analysis renders a different conclusion than the meaning just provided.

The problem is that you have two words conveying uncertainty and/or disbelief in this sentence: ***doubt*** and ***if***. When used together the meaning can be vague. The conjunction “if” presents a hypothetical, which doesn’t really fit with the sentence’s meaning.

The issue with the word doubt is that it is a negative. So if I express doubt, I’m expressing doubt about something. And if it’s about the validity of something, then I have to say what that positive thing is. Not what the negative is, which is what the sentence does.

One of the members expressed doubt if the minister was an **atheist**. It is saying, in effect, that the member doubted the minister was atheist.

Reflecting on my first interpretation, I think the meaning is only made more clear because of the use of the word minister. Ministers aren’t supposed to be atheist, so if one is expressing doubt, it makes more sense that the ***member expressed doubt AND thought the minister might be atheist.***

Here’s a link that could be useful. [https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/25/doubt/#:~:text=If%20you%20really%20doubt%20that,“doubt%20whether%2C”%20though%20it's](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/25/doubt/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20really%20doubt%20that,%E2%80%9Cdoubt%20whether%2C%E2%80%9D%20though%20it%27s)

Comment: I am not sure how you get from the sentence in question that 'They think it possible the minister is a **closeted** atheist'. Couldn't the sentence also be compatible with the minister being widely assumed to be an atheist, and 'one of the members' doubting that assumption (i.e. thinking that it is possible that the minster is a closeted believer).